# How to check if I have a numpy array for any library nickname?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a type checker for a function which needs to check if an argument is of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. However, if `v` is a NumPy array, checking if `type(v) == np.array` eventually depends on how one globally imports `numpy`.

For example if `import numpy` is solely used, then the type checker can't run as `type(v) == np.array` returns an undefined `np` error. Is there any way to get around how one might import numpy yet still check if something is of a numpy type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the output of `type` to string and check if it's `"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"`

This works:

```
import numpy

v = numpy.array([1.])

print(str(type(v)) == "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>")
```

And this too:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1.])

print(str(type(v)) == "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>")
```